# How to access a in-memory variable if its name is passed through JSON?

Tags: javascript, json, variables, global-variables

Seemlingly simple...

If am setting this inside a JavaScript handler:

```
 var storage;
```

Later on I retrieve a JSON dictionary of properties, which I want to set on `storage`. My dictionary looks something like this:

```
 {
   "type": "foo",
   "set_on_global": "storage",
   "property_dict": {
      "some": "thing",
      "baz": "bam"
   }
 }
```

**Question:**
Is there any way to use `set_on_global` to set the `property_dict` object on my global `storage` variable such as:

```
  storage.property_dict = {
    "some": "thing",
    "baz": "bam"
  };
```

Thanks!

**EDIT**:
How to do it, when `storage` is not a global but only kept in memory?

**SOLUTION**:
So this is how it could work. It seems it only works with a setter method, eg:

```
var setter = function (set_on, set) {
 switch (set_on) {
   case "storage":
     storage.property_dict = set;
     break;
 }
```

}

Not a big fan, because it requires hardcoding "storage", so maybe there is another way.

Comment: Since you said `storage` is global, use `window[json.set_on_global].property_dict = json.property_dict;` (where `json` is the JSON you retrieve)

Comment: ok. Got it. What if `storage` is only used in memory and not as a global?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this? You can always access global variable from window object.

```
window[json.set_on_global] = json.property_dict;
```

---

EDITED - Updated to answer follow up question

This depends on whether you have access to it. Let's say it's defined within a class and it's exposed. Then you can do the same thing.

obj[json.set_on_global] = json.property_dict;

Where obj is an instance of that class.

If it's a private variable within a class, then you need to either expose it or have a setter to make this happen.

That's what you are asking, right?

---

EDITED 2

You can try storing storage in an object.

```
var variables = {
    storage: {}
};

var setter = function(instruction){
    variables[instruction.set_on_global] = instruction.property_dict;
}
```

Another way is to just expose the variable so you can it similarly like so (assumed this is a singleton):

```
var Clz = function(){
    var storage = {};

    return {
         storage: storage
    }
}();

Clz[json.set_on_global] = json.property_dict;
```

This should solve your hard-coding issue. I have no idea what kind of class you are trying to create so I thought I gave you a singleton example.

Comment: correct. I'm having trouble setting by using the response of my JSON object only.

Comment: Thanks for now! Still hoping for a simpler way :-)

Comment: What you can do is actually store your variables in an object. Then you can use the same approach.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code:

Assuming `storage` is a global variable in browser code. It can be accessed like `window.storage` or `window['storage']`

```
var json =  {
   "type": "foo",
   "set_on_global": "storage",
   "property_dict": {
      "some": "thing",
      "baz": "bam"
   }
}

var obj = window[json.set_on_global] = {}
obj.property_dict = json.property_dict
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you have to define storage as global

```
window.storage = {};
```

Later, the you got a JSON, just override it

```
window.storage.property_dict = {
    "some": "thing",
    "baz": "bam"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't get it. You have the global `storage`, why cant you just use that to define new properties on it?  Or do you not understand how to traverse the JSON object?

Comment: Actually, `storage` will end up not being a global so I can't use `window[...]`. The rest is easy :-)

Comment: If you want it to be global then remove the 'var' in front.  If you want to keep it namespace scoped, then use the namespace to that variable.  Otherwise, like you said, it's pie.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise against it - you'd be vulnerable to cross-scripting attacks. 
The encapsulation would also advise that your server-side script shouldn't know anything about the internal workings of your client-side script, and the data shouldn't expse them.

So the best course of actions should be using something like:

`storage = json_decode(buffer);`

If you need the data to direct which global variable should get the data, use an identifier code and a switch:

```
"set_on_global" : 1,

    switch(buffer.set_on_global) {
      case 1:
        storage = buffer.property_dict;
    }
```

(off the top of my mind, sintax might be off)

And you'll have your variable set.

EDIT: another answer has proposed a better solution than what I had written below.